# Spring Data Rest: Enable at specific profile only

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-rest

I have added `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` and `spring-boot-starter-data-hateoas` to the dependencies of my project.
However, I don't want to expose the rest api on the productive machine as of yet.
I'm looking for a way of enabling the rest endpoint for one specific profile only.
I have already added `@SpringBootApplication (exclude = {RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class})` and added a configuration

```
@Profile({"dev"})                                                       
@Configuration                                                          
@Import({RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class,                    
 PagedResourcesAssembler.class})                                        
public class DevConfiguration  extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration  {
...
```

But this leaded to nowhere as I couldn't import all classes reported missing.
I'd love to avoid to produce two artefacts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can configure Spring Data REST to only consider repositories that are annotated with `@RepositoryRestResource` or `@RestResource` and don't have the exported flag not set to false. You can add this to your production profile so it won't expose them:

```
@Profile("prod")
@Configuration
public class RepositoryRestConfig extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        config.setRepositoryDetectionStrategy(RepositoryDetectionStrategy.RepositoryDetectionStrategies.ANNOTATED);
    }
}
```

I believe it was added in `2.5.0.RELEASE`

Comment: The double negation of the `RepositoryDetectionStrategy` `ANNOTATED` made by head spinning.
What I did in the end:
I annotated all repositories with `@RepositoryRestResource(exported = false)` and created a Bean based on yours but annotated it with `@Profile("dev")` 
In the overridden method I set the detection strategy to `RepositoryDetectionStrategy.RepositoryDetectionStrategies.ALL`
This means: By default, all repos are disabled. Using the profile "dev" I can enable them.
I will accept you answer as it lead me to the right path!
Thanks!

Comment: Great I could help in some way :) My solution wouldn't require you to add any annotation to your repositories, it'd be the least intrusive way, but both achieve the same result.